# HTML image net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: html, css

i am using html image like this

HTML :

```
<div class="home" style="background: #f2f2f2;">
        <div class="pr_blank"></div>
            <!-- <div id="now" class="show"> -->
        <div class="ptgamebox">

        <img src="../../images/ges.jpg" / ">
        <!-- <em class="game_ro3d"></em> -->
        <div class="game-name">test</div>
        </div>



            </div>
    </div>
```

My images are in a folder like this D:\APP\images\pt\ges.jpg
[image]

Loaded Page Image :

[image]

now when i see in browser this image is being loaded but in console it shows error like this

```
file:///images/ges.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Will someone help me whats wrong with it ?

Comment: What is structure of your files where you load it?

Comment: it was an image

Comment: Where is your HTML file where you load your images?, Edit your Question and post your full directory

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay please refer to the of the div i posted html

Comment: Since your HTML is at the root of APP folder then change your img tag as *`<img src="images/pt/ges.jpg" alt="My Image" />`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img src="APP/images/pt/ges.jpg">
```

If this won't work,

change it like this:

```
<img src="images/ges.jpg"> or <img src="images/pt/ges.jpg">
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this error comes due to control characters... I also face this problem recently, no matters what path I gave (absolute or relative) error remains the same.

Finally I solved this by **NOT COPY pasting PATH** of image

Try to type your image's path by keyboard, you can also copy and paste once, tally the same code by typing and then remove the copy pasted one. Here you have some screenshots from my PC

[This is how error looks likes in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6BIG.png)

[In this image, line no. 13 path is copy pasted, in line 14 I have typed it.... then remove the line 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDXgj.png)

[Finally image start appearing in browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUfLn.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error means that file was not found.Either path is wrong or file is not present where you want it to be. Try to access it by entering source address in your browser to check if it really is there. Browse the directories on server to ensure the path is correct. You may even copy and paste the relative path to be certain it is alright.